# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando adicionar uma chave estrangeira nessa tabela com o seguinte bloco de código

```
public function up()
  {
     Schema::create('registros', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer( 'cliente' )->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer( 'item' )->unsigned()->index();
        $table->decimal( 'vl_preco',10,2 );
        $table->char( 'sn_pago',1 );
        $table->integer( 'qt_compra' )->unsigned();
        $table->foreign( 'cliente' )->references( 'clientes' )->on('id') ;
        $table->foreign( 'item' )->references( 'item' )->on('id') ;
        $table->timestamps();
      });
   }
```

Mas estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table
>   `registros` add constraint `registros_cliente_foreign` foreign key
>   (`cliente`) references `id` (`clientes`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint

As tabelas que estou tentando associar existem e com as repectivas chaves primarias autoincremento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está errado, ou seja, invertido, o correto é

```
$table->foreign( 'cliente' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'clientes' ) ;
```

sendo que o método `references` coloque o ***nome do campo*** que vai construir a relação e método `on` é o ***nome da tabela***.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations)
- [Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Cara! Era isso mesmo... Fiquei ceguinho oh kkk. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se for a resposta do seu problema poderia aceitar como resposta @adventistaam

Answer (score -4):

The same problem occurred to me, I spent several hours researching and trying to execute the corrections proposed in various forums, changing the attribute type, changing the search type, disabling constraints, nothing worked, so I started checking what could happen and came to an interesting solution.

When I created the attribute, I used ->unsigned() , following example:

> Laravel 7x

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
     });
```

In other words, I asked Laravel to create a company_id attribute, such as bigInteger, that did not allow the insertion of a value "zero or less than zero" ->unsigned(), not null (by default it already leaves the new attribute as not null) .

The "users" table already contained records, which caused Laravel to change the table, including a new attribute to it, but it ignored the issue of not accepting the insertion of values zero or less than zero (unsigned) and inserted it in all this table records the new attribute company_id with value 0 (zero).

Next, Laravel, through migrate, tried to change this new attribute (company_id) so that it was a foreign key, but it presented the exception:

General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

The reason for this exception occurs because laravel, before making the foreign key change, checks the attribute rules in all records in the table and this attribute (company_id) being unsigned and having a zero value in the records, it understands that it will not be possible to proceed, which will give an error, displaying this exception and not executing the change.

In my case, I solved the problem with the following implementation: I went to the database, deleted the new attribute (which laravel had already created with a zero value).

When creating the attribute in the migration file, I asked Laravel to include the value 1 as the default (which is the lowest value allowed) and the code looked like this:

> Laravel 7x

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
         $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
     });
```

I saved the file and ran migrate again.

Laravel understood what I requested, created the company_id attribute in the users table, and in the existing records it inserted the value 1 for all of them and then successfully executed the request to transform this attribute into a foreign key of the id attribute in the companies table .

Therefore, check if your database table already has records, if so, set the request to insert default value defaul() as 1 or another integer value greater than 1.

Regarding the issue of Laravel migrate adding an attribute with an incorrect value (zero) even with the unsigned restriction, it would be interesting for the Laravel developers to correct this, as in my opinion it is a failure.

Comment: Esse é [pt.so] e como nome já diz aqui a língua oficial é a língua portuguesa e portanto só ela deve ser utilizada. Por favor, traduza sua publicação para a língua portuguesa.