# Laravel: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho duas tabelas, a tabela `users` e `empresas`, com as Model `User` e `Empresa` respectivamente. Um cadastro de usuário pode gerenciar uma empresa, e para isso, eu preciso definir a qual id o usuário irá acessar na tabela das empresas.

Estou querendo criar uma coluna na table `users` que associa à uma linha da tabela `empresas`. **No entanto, essa coluna pode ser nula.**

Essa é a `Migration` que estou tentando executar para associar a coluna `empresa_id` dentro de `users` para a chave primária em `empresas`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->integer('empresa_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas');
    });
}
```

Definição da coluna `empresas.id`:

```
Schema::create('empresas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
```

A migration da criação da foreign key é a última migration a ser executada com o comando `php artisan migrate:fresh`. Antes desta, as migrations anteriores (incluindo as que criam as tabelas `users` e `empresas`) são executadas sem problemas.

E após executar o comando, recebo o seguinte erro:

> *Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_empresa_id_foreign` foreign key (`empresa_id`) references `empresas` (`id`))*

A tabela `empresas` e `users` já estão criadas.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: O `migrate:fresh` dropa todas tabelas, então não "estão criadas", logo se está tentando adicionar o relacionamento falta `Scheme::create('empresas', ...)` e `Scheme::create('users', ...)` nos métodos `up()`, não entendo muito disto, por isto estou só comentando.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ele dropa tudo e depois roda todas as migrations de novo. Antes dessa migration, já existe as migrations que cria ambas tabelas.

Comment: Ok, roda as migrations na ordem? Tem ou não tem os creates nos ups? Em seu migration só vejo o up para gerar a relação, não vejo "as tabelas", fica dificil dizer o que esta faltando.

Comment: Talvez seja a ordem que as migrations executam, tive um problema parecido uma vez, troquei os nomes das migrations (a data no início) pra reorganizar a ordens de execução e passou funcionar

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de migrations, uso o básico do laravel e o resto acabo fazendo na mão, isso quando uso laravel, pq na pratica acho um baita FW exagerado e mal-performatico, mas não vou ficar criticando, vou logo ao ponto, até aonde me parece um Migration pode representar mais de uma tabela, as pessoas é que tem mania de criar uma tabela para cada migration e esperar que o artisan entenda o que a pessoa fez, logo o método `up()` seria a resposta para criar o que é necessário, mas posso estar falando besteira, de fato só usei migration algumas vezes.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com mais detalhes à respeito da ordem das migrations.

Comment: `bigIncrements` cria uma coluna do tipo `BigInteger`; você criou uma FK do tipo `Integer`. Não há como fazer uma FK referenciar uma PK de tipos diferentes.

Comment: O que acontece é o seguinte, toda vez que vc roda o `php artisan migrate`, ele coloca na fila, tudo que precisa ser processado, até mesmo o que já foi processado, cada vez que vc cria uma nova modificação, vc tem que colocar no método down: `public function down() {...}` o que vai ser dropado... senão ele dá erro quando já existir...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257789/general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @IvanFerrer não é dup, a pergunta está mais para **erro de digitação**, veja o comment do Woss e a resposta dele o problema É OUTRO, o erro desencadeado é o mesmo, mas só porque é um erro generico que diz que não foi possivel relacionar X ao Y.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, por isso é uma possível duplicata, talvez a solução apresentada para o erro nesta outra resposta resolva o mesmo problema dele.

Comment: @IvanFerrer não é nem possivel, o erro é generico, foi semelhante a uma certa vez que outro usuario comentou que era dup um erro 500 de HTTP para uma pergunta se baseando em outra, mas erro 500 é o mais genérico possível, perguntas assim raramente são dups, pois são erros isolados e a mensagem de erro é só generica, só analisando parte a parte do erro do AP para saber o que houve, e pela resposta e comentário do Woss que foi feito 20 minutos antes já deixa tudo isso evidente.

Comment: Então seria o caso de fechar por não estar clara o suficiente, já que é genérica, não há informação suficiente para uma resposta conclusiva. Mas aparentemente, @Woss já respondeu o problema.

Comment: @IvanFerrer sim concordo que faltava detalhes, mas dentro dos poucos que tinha o Woss detectou o erro do AP, logo erro de digitação, pois foi por parte do AP, não que a pergunta tenha que ser deletada, raramente ela pode até ajudar alguém, mas é um erro "impar" mesmo. ;)

Comment: Nem acho que seja um erro de digitação, é um erro de lógica no uso do framework, por mim fica aberta fica aberta mesmo.

Comment: @ErlonCharles como pode ser erro de lógica no FW, se `bigIncrements` indica um tipo de campo (dentro do FW) e `integer` indica outro tipo, logo você dizer que A é do tipo X e deve se comunicar com B (ou através dele) com o tipo Y é o mesmo que esperar que sua tomada seja facilmente conectada em [interruptores "europeus"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntFUb.jpg) (aliás seria mais fácil conectar a tomada mesmo do que fazer um FW entender um erro humano)

Comment: Isso que você acabou de descrever é lógica de interface de tomadas...
Erro de digitação seria escrever `bigIncements` ou `interger`, ou qualquer coisa do tipo, o que aconteceu foi uma falha na implementação do FK no migration.

Comment: Se houver mais discussões acho melhor irmos para um chat! os comentários estão ficando excessivos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao ver a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema), verá:

> `$table->bigIncrements('id')`
>
> Incrementing ID using a "big integer" equivalent.

Ou seja, será criada uma coluna do tipo "big integer" como chave primária.

Na migração você definiu uma chave estrangeira como "integer":

```
$table->integer('empresa_id')
```

Para fazer a relação, os tipos da chave primária e chave estrangeiras devem ser o mesmo. Não pode uma FK referenciar uma PK de outro tipo (mesmo que nesse caso todos os valores possíveis na FK seriam válidos na PK).

Para corrigir, basta definir as colunas com o mesmo tipo:

1. Alterando a FK para `$table->bigInteger('empresa_id')`; ou
2. Alterando a PK para `$table->increments('id')`;

Answer (score -2):

Para criares uma chave estrangeira que aceita o valor null deves adicionar o nullable() antes do constrained(), tal como está abaixo:

```
Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('employ_id')->constrained('employs');
            $table->foreignId('studant_id')->nullable()->constrained('studants');           
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```